# grep doesn't allow me to write `[:alpha:]` when I mean `[:alph]` but other tools do

Tags: python, regex, sed, grep, posix

I am trying to make a regular expression character class that matches strings that contain one or more of the following characters only, and does not contain any other character.

- `:`
- `a`
- `l`
- `p`
- `h`.

Of course, I can do something simple like this and it works.

```
$ printf "foo\nhal\npal\na:h\n" | grep '^[:alph]*$'
hal
pal
a:h
```

But if I try to do something like this, i.e. use redundant characters in the character class, I get an error.

```
$ printf "foo\nhal\npal\na:h\n" | grep '^[:alpha:]*$'
grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]
```

Now, I know what is going on. `grep` "believes" I have mistakenly written `[:alpha:]` when I meant `[[:alpha:]]`.

But isn't `[:alpha:]` a valid regular expression in POSIX? Should it really throw an error for a valid regular expression? Shouldn't it just warn me that I probably meant `[[:alpha:]]`?

In fact, `sed` doesn't complain at all if I use `[:alpha:]` in the regular expression. It behaves exactly like `[:alph]`. I believe `sed` does the right thing.

```
$ printf "foo\nhal\npal\na:h\n" | sed -n '/^[:alpha]*$/p'
hal
pal
a:h
```

Python does the right thing too.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('^[:alpha:]*$', 'foo')
>>> re.search('^[:alpha:]*$', 'hal')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f33d4060f38>
>>> re.search('^[:alpha:]*$', 'pal')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f33d4060920>
>>> re.search('^[:alpha:]*$', 'a:h')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f33d4060f38>
```

It is only `grep` that tries to be smart and tell me that I didn't mean `[:alpha:]` but instead I meant `[[:alpha:]]`.

What does the POSIX standard about it? Does it allow a regex engine to throw an error for `[:alpha:]` or does it require the engine to treat `[:alpha:]` as if it were `[:alph]`?

If could quote the relevant excerpts from the POSIX standard verbatim along with a URL to it , I would consider my question answered.

Comment: Which version of grep do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus grep (GNU grep) 2.18

Comment: GNU grep 2.6.3 has no problem with `'^[:alpha:]*$'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're quite right that "`grep` [is trying] to be smart and tell me that I didn't mean `[:alpha:]` but instead I meant `[[:alpha:]]`" Personally, I don't think that's a terribly bad thing - if `grep` sees `[:alpha:]` in an expression, I'd say that it's much more likely that the person writing it is making a mistake, rather than actually meaning what is *strictly* written.

You're also right that this (arguably helpful) behaviour doesn't [conform to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html). I note, though, that GNU `grep` is affected by the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` which changes its behaviour to make it POSIX-compliant. There is also a [note on the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#invalid_002dbracket_002dexpr) which says:

> If you mistakenly omit the outer brackets, and search for say,
>   ‘`[:upper:]`’, GNU grep prints a diagnostic and exits with status 2, on
>   the assumption that you did not intend to search for the nominally
>   equivalent regular expression: ‘`[:epru]`’. Set the `POSIXLY_CORRECT`
>   environment variable to disable this feature.

Compare:

```
$ printf "foo\nhal\npal\na:h\n" | grep '^[:alpha:]*$'
grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]
```

with.

```
$ printf "foo\nhal\npal\na:h\n" | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 grep '^[:alpha:]*$'
hal
pal
a:h
```

So it looks as if you can switch off this "helpful" behaviour if you *really* don't want it.

Comment: But of course, why are you even duplicating characters in a character class in the first place?